# How to show the number of pictures from a list box

Tags: html

I'm creating a program that rolls a certain amount of dice that the user picks randomly. A window pops up before you start, asking how many dice you want to roll but now I want to change that to a list drop box. I've tried just putting the listbox id as my value but that doesn't work. How do I exactly change the window prompt input to be in my list input?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }
      img {
        height: 150px;
      }
      .document{
        text-size-adjust: 50px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <label># of dice: </label>
        <select id = "myList">
          <option value = "0"> </option>
          <option value = "1">1</option>
          <option value = "2">2</option>
          <option value = "3">3</option>
          <option value = "4">4</option>
          <option value = "5">5</option>
          <option value = "6">6</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="roll()">Click Me!</button>
        <h1>Click the button to see the roll of a die randomly selected</h1>
  <div id="dices"></div>
     </p>
     <hr>
     <p id="display">--</p>
     <script>
      Val = window.prompt("Enter the number of dice to play with (1-5)");
      //if user enters a number <= 1 val ==
      if (Val < 1) {
        Val = 1;
        }
      //if user enters anything thats not 1-4 val = 5
      if (Val > 4) {
        Val = 5
        }
        //Loop to show questionDie
        for (i = 1; i <= Val; i++) {
          let img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = "dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg";
          img.id = "dieImg" + i;
          let dices = document.getElementById("dices");
          dices.appendChild(img);
          }
          function roll() {
            var randomDie = Math.floor(Val*Math.random()) + 1;
            var RandomNum = Math.floor(6*Math.random()) + 1;
            var diceElement = document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie);
            document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie).setAttribute("src","dieImages/die" + RandomNum + ".jpg");
            document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie).style.display="inline";
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "Die " + randomDie + " was selected and rolled to show " + RandomNum;
            }
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've moved most of your code to methods. I've also changed your button click to call one of the methods I created, instead of the `roll` method. I also changed the case of your variable, but not in the `Roll` or `SetUpDice` methods, since I didn't want to risk missing one and spending too much time debugging that.

So here's why your code didn't work: you didn't have it add or remove the dice as per the dropdown, just had it re-roll the existing dice.

You now need to remove the existing dice, since it just keeps adding more and more every time you click the button. Oh, wait, I did that too. I moved the `dices` variable out of the loop, since it wasn't necessary to do it in the loop anyway, and then simply cleared out the HTML that was in it.

FYI, I changed the casing of your variable, since methods are supposed to start with uppercase and variables with lowercase. Well, that's a common convention, anyway.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }
      img {
        height: 150px;
      }
      .document{
        text-size-adjust: 50px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <label># of dice: </label>
        <select id = "myList">
          <option value = "0"> </option>
          <option value = "1">1</option>
          <option value = "2">2</option>
          <option value = "3">3</option>
          <option value = "4">4</option>
          <option value = "5">5</option>
          <option value = "6">6</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" onclick="GetQty()">Click Me!</button>
        <h1>Click the button to see the roll of a die randomly selected</h1>
  <div id="dices"></div>
     </p>
     <hr>
     <p id="display">--</p>
     <script>
      var val = window.prompt("Enter the number of dice to play with (1-5)");
      SetUpDice(val);

    function GetQty() {
      var val = document.getElementById("myList").value;
      SetUpDice(val);
    }

    function SetUpDice(Val) {
      //if user enters a number <= 1 val ==
      if (Val < 1) {
        Val = 1;
        }
      //if user enters anything thats not 1-4 val = 5
      if (Val > 4) {
        Val = 5
        }
        let dices = document.getElementById("dices");
        dices.innerHTML = "";

        //Loop to show questionDie
        for (i = 1; i <= Val; i++) {
          let img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = "dieImages/question-mark-dice.jpg";
          img.id = "dieImg" + i;
          dices.appendChild(img);
        }

        Roll(Val);
      }

      function Roll(Val) {
            var randomDie = Math.floor(Val*Math.random()) + 1;
            var RandomNum = Math.floor(6*Math.random()) + 1;
            var diceElement = document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie);
            document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie).setAttribute("src","dieImages/die" + RandomNum + ".jpg");
            document.getElementById('dieImg' + randomDie).style.display="inline";
            document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "Die " + randomDie + " was selected and rolled to show " + RandomNum;
        }
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```